# problem on connecting to a custom oAuth provider, using next-auth

Tags: oauth-2.0, next-auth

i'm using nextJs and TypeScript to login to a custom oAuth provider(not like google,GitHub or etc).
i made `route.ts` file in `app/api/auth/[...nextauth]` and added the configs like bellow:

```
export const options: any = {
  providers: [
{
    id: 'test',
    name: 'test',
    type: 'oauth',
    version: '2.0',
    check: 'pkce',
    redirectUrl: 'as provided',
    authorizationUrl: 'as provided',
    token: 'as provided',
    clientId: process.env.OAUTH_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSectret: process.env.OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET,
 }
]
}
```

then i made a simple login button like this:

```
import {signIn} from 'next-auth/react'
<button onClick={()=>signIn('test')}>login</button>
```

although i test all that configuration in **postman** and i was able to take token from oAuth provider but i can't do it with the code i provided.
i will be glad if someone can spot my code problem.

in this case i get **405 ERROR**.

also tried using [...nextauth].ts file without making route.ts and  i will be redirect to `api/auth/error`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching, I understood there is an important configuration for the NextAuth library that I missed.
In `.env` file I didn't add `NEXTAUTH_URL` and `NEXTAUTH_SECRET`. Now it's fixed.